# mypy: how to make it correctly guess the type?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-3.10

consider the following example

```
from typing import Callable, Iterable, TypeVar, Any, overload, Tuple, TYPE_CHECKING
from itertools import islice

T = TypeVar("T")

@overload
def mytake(n:int, iterable:Iterable[T]) -> Tuple[T,...]:...
@overload
def mytake(n:int, iterable:Iterable[T], container:Callable[[Iterable[T]],Any]) -> Any:...

def mytake(n:int, iterable:Iterable[T], container:Callable[[Iterable[T]],Any]=tuple) -> Any:
    return container(islice(iterable,n))

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    pass
else:
    reveal_type = print

#a:tuple[int,...]
a = mytake(10,range(100))
reveal_type(a)

#b:list[int]
b = mytake(10,range(100), list)
reveal_type(b)#desired to be list[int]

#c:int
c = mytake(10,range(100),sum)
reveal_type(c)#desired to be int


help(mytake)
```

that ouput

```
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
45
Help on function mytake in module __main__:

mytake(n: int, iterable: Iterable[~T], container: Callable[[Iterable[~T]], Any] = <class 'tuple'>) -> Any
```

Basically just as desire, but I would like that mypy was the same

```
C:\Users\copperfield\Desktop\mypy_tests>mypy test6.py
test6.py:21: note: Revealed type is "builtins.tuple[builtins.int, ...]"
test6.py:25: note: Revealed type is "Any"
test6.py:29: note: Revealed type is "Any"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file

C:\Users\copperfield\Desktop\mypy_tests>
```

Beside type hinting the variables themselves, is there a way to make it so mypy correctly detect the types here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with provisos. Overload resolution is pushing on the edge of mypy's already strained capabilities, so we can get close-ish.

What you want is an additional generic, for the return type of the callable.

```
T = TypeVar("T")
S = TypeVar("S")

@overload
def mytake(n:int, iterable: Iterable[T]) -> Tuple[T,...]:...
@overload
def mytake(n:int, iterable: Iterable[T], container: Callable[[Iterable[T]],S]) -> S:...

def mytake(n:int, iterable: Iterable[T], container: Optional[Callable[[Iterable[T]],S]] = None) -> S:
    if container is None:
        # We're in overload 1
        return cast(S, tuple(islice(iterable, n)))
    else:
        # We're in overload 2
        return container(islice(iterable, n))
```

Note that we have to cast in Case 1, as mypy doesn't consider the overloads that are available when type-checking the *inside* of the function. So we, as human readers, can conclude that, inside that `if` statement, we're in Overload 1, but mypy is still considering that `container` could be *any* `Optional[Callable[[Iterable[T]], S]]`. It's a safe cast, just one mypy doesn't quite get.

This is the signature we want, but it's awkward to work with.

```
#a:tuple[int,...]
a = mytake(10,range(100))
reveal_type(a)
```

The first one still works as intended.

```
#b:list[int]
b = mytake(10,range(100), list)
reveal_type(b)#desired to be list[int]
```

The second one won't work. We actually get an error. Mypy has [some issues](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/9455) with interpreting types as `Callable` instances in generic contexts, so we can get around this using a lambda.

```
#b:list[int]
b = mytake(10,range(100), lambda x: list(x))
reveal_type(b)#desired to be list[int]
```

Not ideal, but workable.

The third one is not so lucky.

```
#c:int
c = mytake(10,range(100),sum)
reveal_type(c)#desired to be int
```

To be quite honest, I'm not even sure what happens here. Mypy reports that the type of `c` is `Union[_T`-1, builtins.int]`. So a union of` int`and an unsolved metavariable. Lovely. I suspect this has to do with the fact that`sum` has [several generic overloads](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L1646) and is probably just confusing mypy. Again, we can get around it with an explicit lambda.

```
#c:int
c = mytake(10,range(100),lambda x: sum(x))
reveal_type(c)#desired to be int
```

So the answer is yes, if you're willing to help the type checker out by generously inserting `lambda` everywhere. But this sort of thing pushes mypy to its limit. I'm not sure if other type checkers would do better generic inference in this case, as I'm most familiar with mypy. If someone has tried this with another Python type checker, feel free to post your results as well.

Comment: I see, `cast` and lambda like that aren't something I'm willing to do, tho... in some other project I was using a bunch of cast to tell mypy that I'm using the correct branch of some union of types, but they simple don't feel right, I feel more like I'm making the program worse (even if just by a nano second) just to please mypy, so I went and remove them all and find my way out of it with overloads... long story short I might want to please mypy but I'm not going to make the program worse for it